# django user created drop down list items

Tags: django, django-models

I want the users to be able to create items from the drop down menu is this possible. I very new to django so any help is appreciated. Currently I'm just saving the title of the item they want to add and have some dummy data as the items.

```
LIST_CHOICES = (
('green','GREEN'),
)

class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('project-create')
```

Is there a way I can get the inputed title from the Listing Model and display it as a dropdown item with Post?

```
 class Post(models.Model):
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=LIST_CHOICES, default='green')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('project-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are working off of pre-existing example code where `LIST_CHOICES` was defined as a static and unchangeable value. (PEP8 standards declare variables in all caps as something that should never change)

You will need to start by creating a new model for department and use a ManyToMany relationship to tie it together with Post and Listing:

```py
class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('project-create')



class Post(models.Model):
    department = models.ManyToManyField(
        to='Listing',
        blank=True
    )
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('project-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Department(models.Model):
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('listing',
                           'post',
                           'name')
```

Django is only tricky at first, but once you get the idea it'll all be much smoother. When I was new to it, the most productive thing I did as a beginner was going through a textbook that walks you through how a blog/cms is developed from start to finish. I'd post a link to the PDF but it was for a much older version of Django.

Try to code along with this book:
https://books.agiliq.com/projects/djenofdjango/en/latest/

it covers a lot of the basics you'll need to learn by typing them out.

Comment: This somewhat works but it returns all the lists not in a drop down. I added a screenshot to my question

Comment: @CodyHost You need to add a `__str__` method to `Listing` to handle what you want.

Comment: @schillingt I'm quite new to django could you please show me how to do this?

Comment: @CodyHost There's one on `Department` that you can copy from.

Comment: @schillingt I did this but its still not a dropdown menu it's now returning the title of the title of the listings but not as a drop down.. is there something I'm still doing wrong?

Comment: It's showing the multiple select because it's a many to many field. You're supposed to be able to select multiple values. If this isn't the case you may want to change your data model. If you want a M2M field and a select form field, then read this and change the widget for the listings to a `Select`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

Comment: @CodyHost Hi Cody, it's hard to tell if you're making changes to admin panel or an already pre-existing form. I'd highly recommend that you try to build these apps first: https://books.agiliq.com/projects/djenofdjango/en/latest/